# opencart 3.0 twig

Tags: opencart, twig

как в шаблоне opencart проверить переменные например делаю так не работает:

```
<?php
 $test = 'test';
 print_r($test);
?>
```

еще что то нашел про: `{{ dump(test) }}` не тоже пустота. Так как быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/)  Проверка переменой на существование:

```
{% if test is defined %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Проверка на наличие значения в переменной:

```
{% if test is null %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Вывести дамп значений переменной:

```
{{ dump(test ) }}
```

Comment: а иногда понадобится в `html` код вызвать какую нибудь функцию, вот как быть в таком случае?

Comment: @newProgrammer теоретически  вызов функции в шаблоне нарушит паттерн MVC и затруднит разбор логики кода. Если вам необходимо работать с возвращаемым значением функции, пакуйте её в контроллере отдельным методом либо в другие методы. Это есть будет правильно.